Message Consumer closed every 1 seconds
I using AMQP Camel to read message from Queue A, add header to the message and send to topic B. There will be 200 message in the Queue A every 300 millisecond. Based on the log file, the JMS MessageConsumer closed every 1 seconds. I don't know why. Can someone give me hint how to prevent the MessageConsumer to close ?
Camel Route
 <bean class="org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory" id="test-connection-pool">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="test-connection-factory"/>
    <property name="maxConnections" value="2"/>
    <property name="maxSessionsPerConnection" value="1000"/>
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.amqp.AMQPComponent" id="amqp">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="test-connection-pool"/>
  </bean>

<routeContext id="test-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route id="route-test">
    <from uri="amqp:queue:Q/A?concurrentConsumers=10&amp;maxConcurrentConsumers=10"/>
    <setHeader name="TEST_HEADER">
    <constant>TEST1234</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <toD uri="amqp:topic:b"/>
  </route>
</routeContext>

Log File
13:48:14.829 [QpidJMS Connection Executor: ID:5a8c0a33-724e-47c1-a243-6a2c724f8222:1] INFO org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession - A JMS MessageConsumer has been closed: JmsConsumerInfo: { ID:5a8c0a33-724e-47c1-a243-6a2c724f8222:1:9:1, destination = Q/A }
13:48:14.839 [Camel (ems-camel) thread #9 - JmsConsumer[Q/A]] WARN org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'Q/A' - trying to recover. Cause: Received disposition with role=receiver delivery-id=128 settled=true: unsupported outcome=modified [condition = amqp:not-implemented
....


I haven't tried this out w/ Camel & AMQP but I think there are two paths forward here:

Test out using "CACHE_CONSUMER" as your cacheLevelName
Try using the CachingConnectionFactory as it very widely used by Solace & JMS users.

